# Caching Array of struct in swift

Tags: swift

I have a struct, which is having some variables in swift. For example:

```
struct ABC {
    //Some Variables
}
```

I am storing it in a NSArray as:

```
var ABCArray : [ABC] = []
```

This array is having some elements of my ABC struct type.

I am trying to cache ABCArray by using:

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(ABCArray) for "someKey"
```

It is trowing me an error saying

> Argument type [ABC] does not conform to expected type AnyObject

How can I cache this array of struct in swift?

Comment: The best technique for archiving a structure or a collection of bit fields is to archive the fields independently and choose the appropriate type of encoding/decoding method for each. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingctypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001294-BBCBDHBI

Answer (score 1):

You declared the array as Swift `Array`, not `NSArray`. Change it to `NSArray` and that should get rid of the error message.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i change my current declaration of swift Array to NSArray?

Comment: var ABCArray = NSArray(array: [something])

Comment: It shows me error: "Cannot create a single-element tuple with an element label"

Comment: The code I suggested throws an error? What version of Xcode? Works fine in Xcode 7.And what is element "label"? I don't see it anywhere in your posted code.